# Count all paths 0-1 board

Tags: c++, count, path, dice

First of all sorry for my English;)

I have a really big problem with this code. I have to create a "game". At the beginning, user set up the size of the board. The board 1xN matrix. Then, he fill it with 0 and 1. Next, user is throwing a dice. If he get number x (x is from 1 to 6 of course), he moves from x cells from left to right. If the value of the cell is 0, he loss, if it is equal to 1 - he is throwing the dice again. User wins, if he get to the right end of the matrix, which is 1 of course.

We have to count all possible paths from left to the right end, labeled 1. Can anybody help me? Here is my code, but it is not finished.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n,p,q;
float a[100];
int T1[100];
int T2[100];
char ster;
int i;
typedef struct gamePathRecord {
std::vector<int> steps;
} gamePath;

std::vector<gamePath> paths;
std::vector<int> tmp;

void countPaths(int* gameArray, int startIndex) {
/*I tried to create funtion using vectors, but I've failed;/
*/
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

printf("How long is your board? From 6 to 100                             \n");
scanf("%d", &n);

if (n>100)

printf("To big board!\n"); 
getche(); return(1); }
if (n<6)
printf("To small board!\n"); 

getche(); return(1); }

printf("Give values of the cells \n");

printf("Number | Value\n");
printf("of cell |of cell\n");
int licznik;
int j;
j=0;
for (licznik=1;licznik<n+1;licznik++)   
{   

 T1[licznik] = scanf("%d", &T1[licznik]  ); 
 if(T1[licznik]==1)
    {T2[j]=licznik;
     j++;
     }

 //printf("%d.       %d \n", licznik, T1[licznik]); 
 } 

 printf("The number of possible paths wynosi: \n");

 int k;
 for(k=1;k<n+1;k=k+1+rand()%6) //symulator kostki do gry
 {if(T1[k]==1)
 {  
 printf("Number of actuall cell %i",k," \n");   
 printf("\n");
 printf("The value of your cell is 1!\n");
}

else
{   printf("Number of actuall cell %i",k," \n");
printf("\n");
printf("I have lost!\n");
break;}
}

getche();
return 0;
}
```

Please help with finnish this project.

Comment: "I tried to create funtion using vectors, but I've failed": What did you tried? Show us your code

Comment: And what are the starting conditions? First roll counted as if starting at index 0 of the array or at index -1 (outside)? If the former, is the content of the first array element (index 0) always 1? Example: If the first roll is a 1 and the move is possible, is then the resulting position 0 or 1?

Comment: So many useless global variables... :$ Do you know what is a class?

Comment: BitTichttp:We start outside the array, I know there is a mess in the code. Class... unfortunately I only know there is something like this. I would be really greatfull if somebody write down ste solution as simple as possible, because I tried to do that all weekend and I have no more ideas;/

Comment: @MichałDulewicz you firstly need to learn the basis of the language. You are like a baby that wants to run, while he cannot even walk.

Comment: I know about that. I am a mathematician, not programist, but teachers at my University want me to write this programe, without learning it.

Comment: @MichałDulewicz Sorry for that, but there are a little stupid, since C++ (and programming) is not a thing you learn in a week. Is C++ the *mandatory* language for the exercise? Because it is a really complex language. If you have choice, prefer some “script” language like python, for example. Anyway, C++ is a **OOP** language: read about it, that may help https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/cp3_OOP.html

Comment: @Boiethios IMHO, there is nothing wrong to write a script-like C++ program for such a given problem. I would probably use a more math-like language, such as F#, ML Haskell etc. for algorithms such as this, but C++ can be used as well. C++ is not a pure OOP language such as Java. You can very well use it as C with standard library types, as a procedural language.

Comment: @BitTickler That is true, everything can be do with C++. But as you say, a more functional language may be more adapted.

Answer (score 0):

The question has not been answered in a while and I kind of feel obliged. But I could not bring myself to write it in C++...at first (see below).

The basic solution to the problem is to recognize, that it is a (directed, acyclic) graph/tree problem and counting all possible routes comes down to count, how many times the target square was hit while performing a depth first search on the tree/graph.

Since - in the comments to the question - it was mentioned that while C++ is perfectly capable of implementing the solution, it might not be the most easy going language to choose. Especially for a mathematician, such as the author of the question, higher languages might be more intuitive.

Whether this theory holds or not, I leave to anyone to judge themselves ;)

Here my F# solution to the problem:

```
// Helper function. It lists the possible jumps from a position i0.
// d = distance list, as computed from board with distances board
let options_from d i0 =
    let rec advance p s result =
        if (i0 + p) < Array.length d
        then
            let x = s + (d.[i0+p])
            if x <= 6 
            then
                advance (p+1) x ((i0 + p) :: result)
            else
                result
        else
            result
    advance 1 0 []

// Converts the [| 0|1... |] board representation into a distance list.
// Yields the distances to the next 1 in the board.
let distances board =
    board
    |> Array.fold (fun (c,l) (x) -> 
            if x = 1 
            then
                1,c :: l
            else
                c+1, l
        ) (1,[])
    |> fun s -> Array.ofList (List.rev (snd s))


// Counts all paths in the depth first search which end on the target index.
let count board =
    let d = distances board
    let end_index = Array.length d - 1
    let rec depth_first_search i =
        match i with 
        | _ when i = end_index ->
            1 // Each time a path ends on end_index, we found an additional path.
        | _ -> 
            // Count all paths to end_index from here.
            options_from d i
            |> List.fold (fun x i1 ->
                    x + depth_first_search i1
                ) 0
    (depth_first_search -1)

let b1 = [| 1;1;1 |]
let b1_paths = count b1

(*
    val b1 : int [] = [|1; 1; 1|]
    val b1_paths : int = 4
*)

let b0 = [| 0;0;1;0;0;1;1;0;0;0;0;0;1; |]
let d = distances b0

(*
    This is how a distance list of b0 looks like:

    val d : int [] = [|3; 3; 1; 6|]
*)

// Test if options_from does what we expect it to do.
let om1 = options_from d -1 
let o0 = options_from d 0 
let o1 = options_from d 1 
let o2 = options_from d 2 
let o3 = options_from d 3

// compute number of paths for board b0
let b0_paths = count b0
(*
    val b0_paths : int = 3
*)
// What will the implementation do if the last entry in board is not a 1?
let b2 = [| 1;1;0 |]
let b2_paths = count b2

(*
    Obviously this implementation does not care...Hm...

    val b2 : int [] = [|1; 1; 0|]
    val b2_paths : int = 2

*)
```

Having the solution in the high level language, it is not all too hard to find an implementation in (modern) C++, too. The C++11 features for iteration come in handy to keep the code concise. Here the nearly direct "translation" of the above F# code to C++.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <exception>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<char> Board_t;

typedef std::vector<int16_t> DistanceList_t;

Board_t ReadNext(std::istream& is)
{
    Board_t result;
    std::string input;
    is >> input;
    for (auto c : input)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
        case '0': result.push_back(0); break;
        case '1': result.push_back(1); break;
        default:
            throw std::exception("Valid input is a string of '0'|'1'. Found something else.");
        }
    }
    return result;
}

DistanceList_t BoardToDistanceList(const Board_t& board)
{
    DistanceList_t result;
    DistanceList_t::value_type d = 1;
    for (auto field : board)
    {
        switch (field)
        {
        case 1:
            result.push_back(d);
            d = 1;
            break;
        default:
            d++;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

std::vector<int32_t> OptionsFrom(const DistanceList_t& d, int32_t i0)
{
    std::vector<int32_t> result;
    int32_t x = 0;
    for (auto p = 1; (i0 + p) < d.size();p++)
    {
        x = x + d[i0 + p];
        if (x <= 6)
        {
            result.push_back(i0 + p);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

size_t DepthFirstSearch(const DistanceList_t& d, int32_t i)
{
    if (i == d.size() - 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        auto move_options = OptionsFrom(d, i);
        size_t count = 0;
        for (auto move : move_options)
        {
            count += DepthFirstSearch(d, move);
        }
        return count;
    }
}

size_t CountPaths(const Board_t& board)
{
    auto d = BoardToDistanceList(board);
    return DepthFirstSearch(d, -1);
}

int main()
{
    bool running = true;
    while (running)
    {
        try
        {
            auto board = ReadNext(std::cin);
            if (board.size() > 0)
            {
                std::cout << "# of paths = " << CountPaths(board) << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                running = false;
            }
        }
        catch (std::exception&ex)
        {
            std::cerr << "Exception: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
            running = false;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "We are done here - have a nice day." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```